# Sculpted mesh reverts to original shape upon exiting sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

I sculpted a mesh but when I exit sculpt mode the sculpted information gets lost and the mesh looks exactly like before I sculpted it. If I go back into sculpt mode the information reappears. How can I apply that sculpt information to the obejct, so it always stays?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been a display error. I entered edit mode once, which fixed it. It was a fairly big mesh, so I could imagine that the display error happened due to insufficient power.

Comment: Thanks for following up with the answer once you figured it out.